# Pandas loc dynamic conditional list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame and I want to find all rows where the i'th column values are 10 times greater than other columns.
Here is an example of my DataFrame:

[image: Sample data]

For example, looking at column i=0, row B (0.344) its is 10x greater than values in the same row but in other columns (0.001, 0, 0.009, 0). So I would like:

```
my_list_0=[False,True,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False]
```

The number of columns might change hence I don't want a solution like:

```
#This is good only for a DataFrame with 4 columns.
my_list_i = data.loc[(data.iloc[:,i]>10*data.iloc[:,(i+1)%num_cols]) &
                     (data.iloc[:,i]>10*data.iloc[:,(i+2)%num_cols]) &
                     (data.iloc[:,i]>10*data.iloc[:,(i+3)%num_cols])]
```

Any idea?
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'cell1':[0.006209, 0.344955, 0.004521, 0, 0.018931, 0.439725, 0.013195, 0.009045, 0, 0.02614, 0],
              'cell2':[0.048043, 0.001077, 0,0.010393, 0.031546, 0.287264, 0.016732, 0.030291, 0.016236, 0.310639,0], 
              'cell3':[0,0,0.020238, 0, 0.03811, 0.579348, 0.005906, 0,0,0.068352, 0.030165],
              'cell4':[0.016139, 0.009359, 0,0,0.025449, 0.47779, 0, 0.01282, 0.005107, 0.004846, 0],
              'cell5': [0,0,0,0.012075, 0.031668, 0.520258, 0,0,0,2.728218, 0.013418]})
i = 0
```

You can use

```
(10 * df.drop(df.columns[i], axis=1)).lt(df.iloc[:,i], axis=0).all(1)
```

To get

```
0     False
1      True
2     False
3     False
4     False
5     False
6     False
7     False
8     False
9     False
10    False
dtype: bool
```

for any number of columns. This drops column `i`, multiplies the remaining df by 10, and checks row-wise for being less than `i`, then returns `True` only if all values in the row are `True`. So it returns a vector of `True` for each row where this obtains and `False` for others.

If you want to give an arbitrary threshold, you can sum the `Trues` and divide by the number of columns - 1, then compare with your threshold:

```
thresh = 0.5  # or whatever you want
(10 * df.drop(df.columns[i], axis=1)).lt(df.iloc[:,i], axis=0).sum(1) / (df.shape[1] - 1) > thresh

0     False
1      True
2      True
3     False
4     False
5     False
6     False
7     False
8     False
9     False
10    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: I don't see how is it going to work (check column i with each and every other column).

Comment: `sum(1)` sums every row. Why don't you check it and see?

Comment: I did check it, hence asking. The condition translates to df.iloc[:,i] > 10*sum_of_row. This doesn't check that df.iloc[:,i] is greater element wise. Do I miss something?

Comment: Edited, in future please copy-paste code rather than image as it saves people having to type it up again from scratch in order to reproduce.

Comment: By the way - is there a Pandas operator "between" .any() and .all()? (i.e. True when some percentage of columns satisfy the condition). I guess I can do it with df.sample(frac=0.5,axis=1) after df.drop.

Comment: Better idea is to sum the number of Trues, and then divide by size of matrix, I've added it to my answer

Comment: Yes, I did something similar - just counted the number of True's and selected based on that:

        data2 = (10* data).lt(data[data.columns[i]], axis=0)                  

        data2['sum_all'] = data2.sum(axis=1)                   

        temp_list = data2.loc[data2.sum_all>=3].index